# Launching an Activity with no UI which starts a service and finishes, but don't want to interrupt the currently running app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

this is more of a style question. Right now, due to Android limitations, in order to get the functionality I am going after, I have to receive an intent with an activity which launches with no UI and doesn't render, starts a service with the intent, and then immediately finishes. However, apps vary in how they react to this launching of another activity. For example, YouTube videos pause. Is there any way I can launch this wrapper activity with as little impact on the app that is currently running as possible?

Comment: I guess it depends on the service - would it be reasonable to just start the service on boot and let it sit in the background doing nothing until you need it?

Comment: It's an IntentService, I'm under the impression that there is not a use case for these where they constantly run in the background

Comment: Additionally, I have to use the wrapper activity because the intent filter only shows up if it's in an activity. (process text intent)

Answer (score 1):

You must use BroadcastReciever. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) you can find a good tutorial about it.

Put it in you Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart ">

   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT">
      </action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Extend BroadcastReceiver

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
         Log.d("AutoStart","Broadcast received");

        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,YourService.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);

    }
}
```

and Finally you can send a broadcast like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```